vba yes/no popup box
I have the following code in my spreadsheet.
What I would like it to do, is rather than look for a Yes in Column 9 is look for a date in Column 8.
If there is a date in column 8, I would like it to show a Yes/No box. If the Yes is selected, I would like it to run the rest of the code, moving the row to a seperate sheet.
Any ideas?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'   Check to see only one cell updated
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column B after row 5 and is set to "Yes"
    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns B to I to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "C"), Cells(Target.Row, "H")).Copy Sheets("S2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub

Tried to add a vb yes/no but it wouldn't follow the rest of the code.

I'm sorry I don;'t understand. What does this mean "Tried to add a vb yes/no but it wouldn't follow the rest of the code."? What did you try?

I managed to get a vbyesno box to appear, but when I click yes/no it didn't follow the rest of the code. This code above is the original code before the vbyesno

Adding a message box is very simple:
Dim user_response As Integer
user_response = MsgBox("DO YOU WANT TO PROCEED?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "THIS IS A QUESTION")

If user_response = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "You choose YES"
    ....
Else
    MsgBox "You choose NO"
    ....
End If


Target

Destination ("Yes")

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MoveRow Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 or modEvents
Sub MoveRow(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Row"
    
    Const TGT_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "H5"
    Const TGT_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "C:H"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "S2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "C"
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' multiple cells changed
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim tfcell As Range: Set tfcell = tws.Range(TGT_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim tprg As Range: Set tprg = tfcell.Resize(tws.Rows.Count - tfcell.Row + 1)
    
    If Intersect(tprg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' wrong cell changed
    If Not IsDate(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub ' cell has no date
    
    Dim MsgResponse As Long
    
    MsgResponse = MsgBox("The changed date is """ _
        & Format(Target.Value, DATE_FORMAT) & """." & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Do you want to move this row?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
    
    If MsgResponse = vbNo Then Exit Sub ' selected "No"
    
    Dim trrg As Range: Set trrg = Target.EntireRow
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = trrg.Columns(TGT_COPY_COLUMNS)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = tws.Parent
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range:
    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    trg.Copy Destination:=dcell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        trrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

